# Fabric.io not updates the portal if not initiate in appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, analytics, fabric.io

I have integrated Fabric.io framework in my code. I have a screen to show to user for his acceptance on fabric so I initiates the fabric in that particular screen but this is not working. I mean session is not updating in this flow.. Where as it works as expected if I keep initiation in didFinishLanuchOptions.

```
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];

    // Enabling debug mode
    [[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share codes of both the tries? Will help to check more regarding the issue.

Comment: Looks more like a bug with Fabric as code looks OK. Got similar thing [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-it-safe-to-init-crashlytics-at-viewcontroller-instead-of-appdelegates-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions/75128)